# c# blur image when uploading

Tags: c#, image, upload, blur

im making an upload for background images on a website and i cant use css because it for some reason lags the whole site as soon as it uses filters.

so what i've desided to do is try and make the image get blurred when the user uploades, but i have no idea how to do it.
i've seen people that has made a huge method to do this task but the results are to be honest poor, but i've also seen people mentioning that there should be something already written in the c# library.

i have no code written to do this yet because nothing i tried worked.

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191557/guassian-smoothening-formula-application

Comment: This website has loads of filters on it and loads fine for me - http://www.inserthtml.com/2012/06/css-filters/ - maybe you're doing something wrong with your filters to make it lag so much when loading?

Comment: What im looking for is how i can blur an image when it is uploaded.

And all i did with the filters was add -webkit-filters:blur(5px); nothing more and then is started lagging when ever i scroll.

Answer (score -1):

```
namespace Services
{
    public class ImageBlur : AbstractProcessing
    {
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(imageBlur);
        g.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
        //image.MakeTransparent();
        int x = (imageBlur.Width - image.Width) / 2;
        int y = (imageBlur.Height - image.Height) / 2;
        g.DrawImage(image, new Point(x, y));
        return imageBlur;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you could add some explanation in your answer.